is 5/8" sheet rock acceptable for a HVAC closet
Is 5/8" sheet rock suitable for a 4'x4'x4'x8'HVAC closet?  Previous builder did not sheet rock behind a HVAC system in a residential home and homeowner not able to sell home.

Who is not allowing them to sell their home in this situation?  Ask them what is required, not people on the internet who have no idea of the location or local code requirements (if any).

I was told that told that since a building permit is still open it shows up on the search the realtors di and building inspector won't pass the HVAC install since no sheet rock behind the air handler in the HVAC closet.

Open permits can be a huge problem. Talk to the AHJ.

What is the AHJ?   Air Handler Judge?

AJH - Authority Having Jurisdiction.  Usually a building inspector through the permitting authority.

What would be the rationale for requiring sheetrock in an HVAC closet, anyway?  Other than possibly accoustic separation?

Probably some sort of fire blocking, similar to drywall requirements between an attached garage and a habitable dwelling.

@AlexBello -- what are the governing building codes in your area?

Ask the building inspector what is required since they'll need to be the one to sign off on the permit completion and approve the work.  There's really no other answer in this situation since we don't know your location or local requirements.
